# UICollectionView with self sizing collapsing cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create collection view with dynamic height cells which could collapse/expand. It should work since ios11 version so I don't use Compositional Layout. It's pretty easy to make collectionview with dynamic height cells:

ViewController Implementation:

```
final class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributesObjects = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map{ $0.copy() } as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        layoutAttributesObjects?.forEach({ layoutAttributes in
            if layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .cell {
                if let newFrame = layoutAttributesForItem(at: layoutAttributes.indexPath)?.frame {
                    layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
                }
            }
        })
        return layoutAttributesObjects
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            fatalError()
        }
        guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes else {
            return nil
        }

        layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x = sectionInset.left
        layoutAttributes.frame.size.width = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CollapsingCellDelegate {
    let items = [
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                "Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.",
        ]

    private var collapsedSections: [IndexPath] = []
    private var collapsedItems: [IndexPath] = []

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = CustomFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CollapsingCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollapsingCell.identifier)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    // Collapse/Expend Magic Here
    func didTriggerCollapseEvent(cell: CollapsingCell) {
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        if collapsedItems.contains(indexPath) {
            self.collapsedItems.removeAll(where: { $0 == indexPath })
        } else {
            collapsedItems.append(indexPath)
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        })
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollapsingCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollapsingCell
        myCell.isCollapsed = collapsedItems.contains(indexPath)
        myCell.delegate = self
        myCell.configure(title: "Cell #\(indexPath.row)", contentTitle: items[indexPath.row])
        return myCell
    }
}
```

Collapsing CollectionViewCell Implementation:

```
protocol CollapsingCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didTriggerCollapseEvent(cell: CollapsingCell)
}

public class CollapsingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var isCollapsed: Bool? {
        didSet {
            contentLabel.isHidden = isCollapsed ?? false
        }
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        String(describing: self)
    }

    weak var delegate: CollapsingCellDelegate?
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let collapseButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private let stackView = UIStackView()
    private let contentLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 9
        contentView.backgroundColor = .white

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)

        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.textColor = .black
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
        headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        collapseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(collapseButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        collapseButton.setTitle("Collapse/Expend", for: .normal)
        collapseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        headerView.addSubview(collapseButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(headerView)

        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        contentLabel.textColor = .black
        contentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            collapseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.centerYAnchor),
            collapseButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),

            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc func collapseButtonTapped() {
        delegate?.didTriggerCollapseEvent(cell: self)
    }

    func configure(title: String, contentTitle: String) {
        titleLabel.text = title
        contentLabel.text = contentTitle
    }

    public override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width, height: 0)
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
        layoutAttributes.frame.size = size
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6DCC.png)

Works Like a charm until the collapse/expand check. As you can see there is a basic stackview inside the cell, and two views inside the stackview: header and contentView. When collapse button pressed, content view visibility changes, so stackview change its size and cell size at the same time. All we have to do is reload this cell.

For some reason it works for first cells but collectionview breaks if try to collapse cell at the end of list:

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byzQ4.jpg)

I tried to change my animateWithDuration block and reload items/hole collection/invalidateLayout inside the performBatchUpdates block, but the best case scenario I got another bugs.

I would appreciate any help. Project on [github](https://github.com/rubidus1/CollapseTest)